# Zoom in/out canvas with keeping drawn points

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I loaded picture to canvas and draw couple points within this very simple function:

```
var addPoint = function($x, $y, $context) {
    $context.fillStyle="#FF0000";
    $context.fillRect($x, $y, 3, 3);
    $("#points").append(
      $("<li>").append("Point nr "+ totalPoints()).append(
        "<a href='#' class='remove_point' data-x='"+$x+"' data-y='"+$y+"'>[delete]</a>"
      )
    );
    bindRemove($context);
  };
```

I would like to add zoom feature. I suppose that I need to use `scale()` function on my canvas context to achieve my goal. Problem is I want to keep all points (rectangles) drawn on canvas before. I stored those points on simple `ul` list. After executing scale() I need to redraw canvas and probably will loose those points. After zoom in/out coords for them are different and needs to be calculated again.

How I can zoom my canvas and keep previously added points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image][image]

Yes, you can store all your rectangle definitions using javascript objects inside an array.

```
var rects=[];
rects.push({x:20,y:20,width:25,height:15,color:'red'});
rects.push({x:75,y:100,width:50,height:35,color:'green'});
rects.push({x:150,y:75,width:40,height:75,color:'blue'});
rects.push({x:100,y:225,width:50,height:50,color:'gold'});
```

Then to zoom you can:

- clear the canvas
- scale the canvas with `context.scale`
- use the rectangle objects to redraw all your rectangles
- unscale the canvas in preparation for any future drawings

Here's example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var $canvas=$("#canvas");
var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

var scale=1.00;

var rects=[];
rects.push({x:20,y:20,width:25,height:15,color:'red'});
rects.push({x:75,y:100,width:50,height:35,color:'green'});
rects.push({x:150,y:75,width:40,height:75,color:'blue'});
rects.push({x:100,y:225,width:50,height:50,color:'gold'});

drawRects();

//
function drawRects(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  ctx.scale(scale,scale);
  for(var i=0;i<rects.length;i++){
    var r=rects[i];
    ctx.fillStyle=r.color;
    ctx.fillRect(r.x,r.y,r.width*scale,r.height*scale);
  }
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
}


//
canvas.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll',handleScroll,false);
canvas.addEventListener('mousewheel',handleScroll,false);


//
function handleScroll(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  var delta=e.wheelDelta?e.wheelDelta/30:e.detail?-e.detail:0;
  if (delta){
    scale+=(delta>=0)?.01:-.01;
    drawRects();
  }
};
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Click in Canvas then use mousewheel to zoom</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=400></canvas><br>
```